# Userstyles in Firefox for Android

Tags: firefox-for-android

Originally posted on SuperUser, I have been redirected here.

Is there a sane way to use custom userstyles in Firefox for Android? I know Stylish has an addon, but I don't want to use it due to recent privacy concerns. On desktop I use StylRRR Barebone Userstyles Injector.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! I could cascade your redirect: if you're specifically looking for an addon, [our sister site](https://meta.android.stackexchange.com/q/2060/16575) would be the better place. But as you've phrased it, it is well on-topic here – so don't feel "pushed off" :)